# list files recursive up to a certain level in R

Tags: r

Is there an elegant way to list files recursive up to a certain level?
I have a very complicated folder structure und it takes several seconds to search for all `xml` files recursively. For me it would be enough to search only up to a certain level, but the code I developed looks ugly and I was wondering if there is a more elegant way. It would turn out ugly to search up to the 4th level for example...

```
list.files(c(list.dirs(recursive=FALSE), # first level
             list.dirs(list.dirs(recursive=FALSE), recursive=FALSE)), # second level 
             pattern='\\.xml$',
             full.names=TRUE, 
             recursive=FALSE)
```

Comment: Maybe set recursive to TRUE and use a filter discarding instances with more than N "/"s?

Comment: the `list.dirs` function already takes a long time, since the complex folder structure... So I would prefer to really just search until a specific depth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For elegance, I would write a small recursive utility with an `n` parameter that you can use afterwards. E.g. something like:

```
list.dirs.depth.n <- function(p, n) {
  res <- list.dirs(p, recursive = FALSE)
  if (n > 1) {
    add <- list.dirs.depth.n(res, n-1)
    c(res, add)
  } else {
    res
  }
}

list.dirs.depth.n(".", n = 3)
```

And then use this in your call to `list.files`

Comment: This is what I tried but I couldn't get it running in a way... Will give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using `Sys.glob`:

```
getFiles <- function(ext, depth){
  wildcards <- Reduce(
    file.path, x = rep("*", depth), init = paste0("*.", ext),
    right = TRUE, accumulate = TRUE
  )
  Sys.glob(wildcards)
}
getFiles("xml", 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

This example is very similar to the recursive solution #1, but it is done for files.

```
lfbl=function(pattern,level=1){
    if(!exists("lof")) lof=vector("character",0)
    temp=list.files(pattern=pattern,no..=T)
    if(!is.na(temp[1])) lof=c(lof,paste0(getwd(),"/",temp))
    if(level>0){
        dirf=list.dirs(full.names=F,recursive=F)
        for(i in dirf){
            setwd(i)
            lof=c(lof,lfbl(pattern,level-1))
            setwd("..")
        }
    }
    return(lof)
}
```