# Loop over all subdirectories and read in a file in each subdirectory

Tags: r

I have an output directory from dbcans with each sample output in a subdirectory. I need to loop over each subdrectory are read into R a file called overview.csv.

```
for (subdir in list.dirs(recursive = FALSE)){
  data = read.csv(file.path(~\\subdir, "overview.csv"))
}
```

I am unsure how to deal with the changing filepath in `read.csv` for each subdir. Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up front, the `~\\subdir` (not as a string) is obviously problematic. Since `subdir` is already a string, using `file.path` is correct but with just the variable. If you are concerned about relative versus absolute, you can always normalize the paths with `normalizePath(list.dirs())`, though this does not really change things if you use `

A few things to consider.

1. Constantly reassigning to the same variable doesn't help, so either you need to assign to an element of a `list` or something else (e.g., `lapply`, below). (I also think `data` as a variable name is problematic. While it works just fine "now", if you ever run part of your script without assigning to `data`, you will be referencing the *function*, resulting in possibly confusing errors such as `Error in data$a : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`; since a `closure` is really just a function with its enclosing namespace/environment, this is just saying "you tried to do something to a function".)
2. I think both `pattern=` and `full.names=` might be useful to switch from using `list.dirs` to `list.files`, such as

   ```r
   datalist <- list()
   # I hope recursion doesn't go too deep here
   filelist <- list.files(pattern = "overview.csv", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
   for (ind in seq_along(filelist)) {
     datalist[[ind]] <- read.csv(filelist[ind])
   }
   # perhaps combine into one frame
   data1 <- do.call(rbind, datalist)
   ```
3. Reading in lots of files and doing them same thing to all of them suggests `lapply`. This is a little more compact version of number 2:

   ```r
   filelist <- list.files(pattern = "overview.csv", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
   datalist <- lapply(filelist, read.csv)
   data1 <- do.call(rbind, datalist)
   ```

   Note: if you really only need precisely *one* level of subdirs, you can work around that with:

   ```r
   filelist <- list.files(list.dirs(somepath, recursive = FALSE),
                          pattern = "overview.csv", full.names = TRUE)
   ```

   or you can limit to *no more than* some depth, perhaps with `list.dirs.depth.n` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48300309.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a very useful and well explained answer! How do I input options into `datalist <- lapply(filelist, read.csv)` for `read.csv`, such as `header = TRUE` ?

Comment: I came to use solution of this: `datalist = lapply(filelist, function(i){
  read.table(i, header = TRUE)
})`

Is this reasonable or messy?

Comment: `datalisr <- lapply(filelist, read.table, header=TRUE)` should work, too.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be this.

```
for (subdir in list.dirs(recursive = FALSE)){
    data = read.csv(paste0(subdir, "overview.csv"))
}
```