# List nested Excel files in R directories

Tags: r, excel, regex, import, readr

I have the following directory structure that I'm working with on Windows 10.

```
C:
├── my-R-working-directory/
    ├── excel01.xlsx
    ├── excel02.xlsx
    ├── nested-folder-A
    |   ├── excel03.xlsx
    └── nested-folder-B
        └── excel04.xlsx
```

I can list all the Excel files directly within my working directory with the following command:

```
getwd()
#> "C:/my-R-working-directory"

list.files("path/of/folder", pattern = "\\.xlsx$", full.names = TRUE)
#> [1] "C:/my-R-working-directory/excel01.xlsx
#> [2] "C:/my-R-working-directory/excel02.xlsx
```

What regular expression can I use for the `pattern` argument to list all Excel files one nested level deep? In other words I only want to see Excel files in `nested-folder-A` and `nested-folder-B`, which would be `excel03.xlsx` and `excel04.xlsx` (and any other Excel files that are in folders that happen to be one level deep).

My thought was to use what you see below, but it returns `character(0)`, which I assume means my regular expression is wrong:

```
list.files("path/of/folder", pattern = "\\\\.xlsx$", full.names = TRUE)
#> character(0)
```

I took the `pattern = "\\.xlsx$"` that looks in the working directory and tried to go one level up, ie `pattern = "\\\\.xlsx$"`. Attempt failed. What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you looked at the `recursive` argument in `list.files()` it lets you see the files in lower level directories. In conjunction with `pattern = "\\.xlsx$"` will match the Excel files in all recursive directories.

`list.files("path/of/folder", pattern = "\\.xlsx$", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)`

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48297440/list-files-recursive-up-to-a-certain-level-in-r) might help if you want to do level-specific recursive list files.

Comment: why do we need $ at the end ?