# How to list.files() until n level deep subdirectory in R

Tags: r

I have a very complex organisation of folders, and here is a simplified version of it.

```sh
       |--Folder0 --- Folder0.1
       |
home---|--Folder1 --- Folder1.1 --- Folder1.2
       |
       |--Folder2 --- Folder2.1
```

I want to list from the second level folders (Folder0.1, Folder1.1, Folder2.1)
all the .xlsx files.

Any help is really appreciated.

**Please do not take for granted the name of the folders. Only for simplification I called them like this.** Their names come as a random.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`list.files(recursive=)` doesn't allow an immediate limit, I suggest three paths:

1. Get all, split on the file-separator (typically `/`) and limit the listing.

   ```r
   allfiles <- list.files(".", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
   under5 <- allfiles[ lengths(strsplit(allfiles, "/")) < 6 ]
   ```

   Since it likely starts with `"."`, you may need one more than you think you do. Experiment with the `6` here to get what you need.
2. If it's only a few deep, then construct the list of directories manually and disable `recursive` completely.

   ```r
   dir1 <- list.dirs(".", recursive=FALSE)
   dir2 <- list.dirs(dir1, recursive=FALSE)
   dir3 <- list.dirs(dir2, recursive=FALSE)
   dir4 <- list.dirs(dir3, recursive=FALSE)
   allfiles <- setdiff(list.files(c(dir1, dir2, dir3)), c(dir1, dir2, dir3))
   ```

   (Admittedly under-tested, not awesome, but it's a start of a method.)
3. Use `system("find . -maxdepth 5 -type f", intern=TRUE)` or similar to produce file names.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `list.files(recursive = TRUE)` then filtering the result is a valid approach, but it is error-prone and doesn't scale well with the size and depth of the file system tree that you are recursing over.

I would consider calling one of the command line utilities provided by your OS, which you can do via R's `system` and `system2`. For example, on Unix, you could simply do:

```r
system("find . -maxdepth n -type f -regex '.*[.]xlsx'", intern = TRUE)
```

replacing `n` with your desired recursion depth. An advantage of this approach is that `find` is highly optimized and has many (many) more options than `list.files`.

Another scalable option is to write your own recursive function that stops where you want. Below is one possibility, which you should probably test more than I have.

```r
lf <- function(path = ".", maxdepth = 0L, pattern = NULL, all.files = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE) {
    fn <- list.files(path, pattern = pattern, all.files = all.files, full.names = TRUE, no.. = TRUE)
    dn <- list.dirs(path, full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE)
    fn <- fn[match(fn, dn, 0L) == 0L]
    if (!all.files) {
        dn <- dn[grepl("^[^.]", basename(dn))]
    }
    if (length(dn) == 0L) {
        return(fn)
    }
    if (maxdepth < 1L) {
        if (include.dirs) {
            return(c(fn, dn))
        } else {
            return(fn)
        }
    }
    l <- lapply(dn, lf, maxdepth = maxdepth - 1L, pattern = pattern, all.files = all.files, include.dirs = include.dirs)
    if (include.dirs) {
        l <- Map(c, dn, l, USE.NAMES = FALSE) 
    }
    c(fn, unlist(l, FALSE, FALSE))
}
```

Then:

```r
lf(".", maxdepth = n, pattern = "[.]xlsx$")
```

again replacing `n` with your desired recursion depth.

Answer (score 1):

Would like to chime in for a similar solution to [Mikael Jagan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12685768/mikael-jagan)'s solution after being inspired by this question: [list files recursive up to a certain level in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48297440/list-files-recursive-up-to-a-certain-level-in-r)
I made a function to list folder from a specific depth.

```
list_dir_n_depth <- function(path_use, depth_keep = 1){
    # Initiate
    path_list = list()
    level = 1
    path_list[[level]] = path_use # initiate first level 
    q = path_list[[level]]

    # loop it till no child level left, or reached depth_keep
    while(length(q) > 0 & level < depth_keep){
        level = level + 1 # Advance one level to add all the child nodes
        path_list[[level]] = vector() # initiate child list

        for(i in seq(length(q), 1, -1)){ # when there are more than one item, collect all the child for next level 
            all_childs_this_dir = list.dirs(q[[i]], recursive = FALSE) # get all childs
            path_list[[level]] = c(path_list[[level]], all_childs_this_dir) # Add to current level list
        }

        # Get all items from next level
        q = path_list[[level]]
        
    }
    # retrun the level to print
    if(depth_keep > length(path_list)) return(NULL) else return(path_list[[depth_keep]])
}
```

For instance, I have a folder structure set like this

```
.
├── folder1
│   ├── fd11
│   │   ├── file1.xlsx
│   │   └── file2.xlsx
│   ├── fd12
│   │   ├── file121.xlsx
│   │   └── file1.xlsx
│   ├── fd13
│   ├── fileA.xlsx
│   └── fileB.xlsx
├── folder2
│   ├── fd21
│   │   ├── file23.xlsx
│   │   └── file33.xlsx
│   └── fd22
└── folder3
    ├── df31
    ├── df32
    ├── df33
    │   ├── file34.xlsx
    │   └── file36.xlsx
    └── df34
```

Using this function gets `list_dir_n_depth("PATH/TO/YOUR/DIR", depth_keep = 3)`

```
[1] "/folder3/df31" "/folder3/df32" "/folder3/df33" "/folder3/df34"
[5] "/folder2/fd21" "/folder2/fd22" "/folder1/fd11" "/folder1/fd12"
[9] "/folder1/fd13"
```

and the combo get all the xlsx under folder level 3

```
list_dir_n_depth("PATH/TO/YOUR/DIR", depth_keep = 3) %>% list.files(pattern = 'xlsx', full.names = F)

[1] "file1.xlsx"   "file1.xlsx"   "file121.xlsx" "file2.xlsx"   "file23.xlsx"
[6] "file33.xlsx"  "file34.xlsx"  "file36.xlsx"
```

And to get xlsx one level up

```
list_dir_n_depth("PATH/TO/YOUR/DIR", depth_keep = 2) %>% list.files(pattern = 'xlsx', full.names = F)

[1] "fileA.xlsx" "fileB.xlsx"
```

Of note, set `full.names = T` in `list.files` to get the full path of the files

For instance if want to keep only the xlsx in folder `fd21`, can `grep` or `str_subset` from `stringr` to futher filter the result

```
# str_subset
list_dir_n_depth("PATH/TO/YOUR/DIR", depth_keep = 3) %>% 
    list.files(pattern = 'xlsx', full.names = T)  %>% 
    str_subset('fd21')

# grep
list_dir_n_depth(TEST, depth_keep = 3) %>% 
    list.files(pattern = 'xlsx', full.names = T)  %>% 
    .[grep('fd21', .)]

[1] "PATH/TO/YOUR/DIR/folder2/fd21/file23.xlsx"
[2] "PATH/TO/YOUR/DIR/folder2/fd21/file33.xlsx"
```